# How to clear Transients on all sites in Multi Sites environment

Tags: transient, wp-cli

I know we have the following command available in `WP-CLI` to remove transients

```
# Delete all transients
$ wp transient delete-all
```

However, my question is does it remove transients on all sites over multi sites? If not how can we remove transients on all sites?

Answer (score 1):

You can run any command against all sites in a network by combining the `wp site list` and the `| xargs`:

```
wp site list --field=url | xargs -n1 -I % wp --url=% transient delete --all
```

Source: https://runcommand.io/to/run-wp-cli-command-wordpress-multisite/

Comment: So, does wp transient delete --all --network ONLY delete network-level transients then, not all transients in the network (also on sub-sites)?

Comment: @david, i think its missing a space and dash in: `transient delete --all`

Comment: @Adam Yes. Otherwise use --url as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because not all server work with pipe xargs syntax (`| xargs`), I prefer the other syntax, `for in`. Also, because it is more comprehensible and allow to chain commands like so :

```
for url in $(wp site list --field=url --url={dom.fr}); do
wp option get siteurl --url=$url;
wp transient delete --all --url=$url;
wp cache flush --url=$url;
wp rewrite flush --url=$url;
wp cron event run --due-now --url=$url;
done;
```

*(for display purpose I have added newlines, please delete them when copying in command line to paste one line)*

1. List all multisite's sub-sites: `wp site list --field=url --url={dom.fr}`. Always precise the `--url` in multisite with your `domain.extension`. The parent site could not be the first one.
2. Then, iterating on all these sites with something similar to a foreach loop.
3. I firstly added more information with `wp option get siteurl` to know in the command line which site is currently used. Usefull when working with a ton of sub-sites.
4. Then lunch all the commands I want against a website with WP CLI. In this example, I delete all transients, flush the cache, flush the rewrites, even lunch the cron. It is limited to the current website in the foreach loop due to the `--url` arg.

The output will be something like that:

```
https://site.docksal
Success: 6 transients deleted from the database.
Success: The cache was flushed.
Success: Rewrite rules flushed.
Success: Executed a total of 0 cron events.
https://en.site.docksal
Success: 4 transients deleted from the database.
Success: The cache was flushed.
Success: Rewrite rules flushed.
Success: Executed a total of 0 cron events.
```

For more WP CLI samples, see my gist https://gist.github.com/MaximeCulea/575e493a061359edbb12cefc3aa4c770#file-wp-cli-ms-cheatset-php-L38